# Status of rdp session manager sesman fail

Tags: 14.04, server, remote-desktop, xrdp

I was using xrdp to remotely connect from my Windows laptop to Ubuntu server. It was doing ok but failed after a weekend all out of sudden. I did a `>#service xrdp status` and it returned:

```
* Checking status of Remote Desktop Protocol server xrdp                [ OK ]
* Checking status of RDP Session Manager sesman                         [fail]
```

I cannot find the solutions anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. For me I had to run the command with `sudo` in front of it, and it reported back "OK".

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions**
i tried below steps it's working fine now.
Steps:

1. Uninstall xrdp service
2. Update the patch
3. reboot the server
4. Again install the xrdp service & restart it connected. If it's not working do it step 5
5. edit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
   startwm.sh
   (pay attention to the last line):
   [startwm.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ONPw.png)
6. To make all these changes effective, restart xRDP as such:
   [XRDP Service Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G83V1.png)

*Note:Also check with RDP port enable in your server